# Firebase RealTime db using python , how to check if userName exist

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

am using python to check if a user exist in firebase RealTime DB. Here is my structure
[image]

data =  {"email": "test@gmail.com"   "phone":"123" , "id":"321"}

before i create a new user in my DB, i wanna check if the user's email already exist in the db by using python

Comment: What SDK/library are you using to read from the database?

Comment: am just beginner, never used to read data from db. but i know am using pyrebase with python

Answer (score 0):

To check if a value already exists in the Firebase Realtime Database, you can [use a query](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#complex-queries). Based on that link, yours would look something like this:

```
users_by_email = db.child("Users").order_by_child("email").equal_to("Testing22@....com").get()
```

Reading the data from that query then works the same as shown in the documentation on [reading data](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#retrieve-data).